# CSS margin issue

Tags: html, css

Sorry about the simple question..

do anyone know why my images on the button section of this page are not aligning correctly. the image on the far right seems to be pushed down. Doesn't anyone know what's causing this problem?

[Link to Issue](http://www.iamnatesmithen.com/ExpressionEngine2/index.php/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove any spaces or new line between `</li>` and `<li>`, so in the HTML mode of your CMS it should literally read `</li><li>` and not something like:

```
</li>



        <li>
```

If that's somehow not possible, contact the developers / forum of your CMS and ask there for help.

Answer (score 5):

You have a bunch of `&nbsp`'s that aren't in tags. Looks like that seem to be the issue after removing them via Firebug. Remove them and it should line up.

Comment: Think that's caused by the CMS - expression engine. These are fields created by expression engine

Comment: I'm not too familiar with expression engine, but if that's what it's doing you should work through the code and figure out how to make it stop.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of white space after deleting it: [image]

Comment: I think you need another edit (as your last one made the sentence read weird), I don't think deletion introduces white space and you might want to explain what *it* is that you are deleting. :)

Comment: @Tom Wijsman i actually don't know what i'm deleting, what ppl are mentioning on here isn't showing on my html??

Answer (score 1):

When I inspect the page I see extra html elements inserted into the document

```
</li><!-- ITEM ENDS HERE -->
 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<li class="item2">
```

The extra "nbsp"s are throwing off the alignment.

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid html. You need to fix that first. Run your page through a validator and correct the "Element div not allowed as child of element ul in this context" errors.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of whitespaces above each `<li>`. Remove them and it should work fine. Use Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug to check 'em out.